# PowerApps Portal - Form with checkboxes + Submit

Tags: powerapps, power-platform, powerapps-portal

I wanted to make a form that would have multiple sentences with one checkbox each. When all of them are accepted (ticked) i wanted to have a submit button to become enable (previously disabled).

Is it possible? How can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like below :

```
If(Checkbox3.Value && Checkbox2.Value && Checkbox1.Value,DisplayMode.Edit,Disabled)
```

[image]

When everything is checked :

[image]

**Code explanation :**

It does an `& - And`  Operation for all the checkbox values and if all are true (Checked), then the button displaymode will Edit else will be in disabled state.

[image]

Comment: Please consider accepting this solution if it had helped :)
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work